# Ruby JSON.parse gives unexpected token error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm sending a POST with jQuery like this

```
   var authorisationType = "payment";

   var paymentData = {
        cardholdername: $("#userCardName").val(),
        cardnumber: $("#userCardNumber").val(),
        expmonth: $("#userExpMonth").val(),
        expyear: $("#userExpYear").val(),
        cvv:$("#userCVV").val(),
        amount: "$15.00"
    }

    var postData = new Object();
    postData.username = username;
    postData.type = authorisationType;
    postData.data = paymentData;

    var authorisationType = "payment";

    console.log("sending username and token to server");
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
       data: JSON.stringify(postData), 
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: successHandler,
       error: errorHandler
    });
```

to my Rails controller:

```
def authorisation_request
    puts "preparse" 
    hash = JSON.parse(params[:username])
    puts "hash" 
    puts "username:" + JSON.parse(params[:username]).to_s + " type:" +  JSON.parse(params[:type]).to_s + " data:" + JSON.parse(params[:data]).to_s
end
```

And I get the following error in the Console:

```
 Parameters: {"username"=>"me@example.com", "type"=>"payment", "data"=>{"cardholdername"=>"me myself", "cardnumber"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxx3456", "expmonth"=>"01", "expyear"=>"2015", "cvv"=>"999", "
amount"=>"$15.00"}, "session"=>{"username"=>"me@example.com", "type"=>"payment", "data"=>{"car
dholdername"=>"me myself", "cardnumber"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxx3456", "expmonth"=>"01", "expyear"=>"2015"
, "cvv"=>"999", "amount"=>"$15.00"}}}

preparse
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at 'me@example.com'):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:119:in `authorisation_request'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params[:username]` contains string (`me@example.com`) which is not a valid JSON. You don't need to call `JSON.parse` on this.

Answer (score 3):

It'd be much cleaner and easier for you if you post data from your jQuery like this:

```
var postData = new Object();
postData.userdata = { 'username': username, 
                      'type': authorisationType,
                      'data': paymentData };
```

Now, in controller, you can:

```
def authorisation_request
  puts params[:userdata]
end
```

No need of `JSON.parse` as all values are available in parameter as key-value pair using `params`.

Comment: +1 because although it does not answer the question directly, it gives great advice on best practices and makes the question irrelevant. The parameters can now be accessed like: params[:userdata][:username], and so on. Thanks!